# How to SELECT between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, select, between

I need to give a select count in a table using the range of two dates, however my dates are in "yyyy-MM-dd" format, and when I execute the select SQL it returns the following error:

> Converting a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in a value out of range

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS score 
FROM requests 
WHERE date_em BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30'
```

Table structure

- date_em = DATETIME

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use `20190401` and `20190430` as the date constants (without dashes), as that format is unambiguously converted to a datetime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My preferred method is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS score
FROM requests
WHERE date_em >= '2019-04-01' AND
      date_em < '2019-05-01'
```

This handles the time component and will make use of an index.

The following also works well in SQL Server:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS score
FROM requests
WHERE CONVERT(date, date_em) BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30'
```

In SQL Server, this will also use an index (if available).  However, normally functions on columns preclude the use of an index, so I'm more hesitant about this approach.

Comment: Your case 2 is perfect! It worked well here. Thank you! @GordonLinoff

Comment: Since this is using dates, you should be aware of [this behavior](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/) with using `BETWEEN` @GuilhermeStichtenoth

Comment: If you're using BETWEEN, make sure do look at the EXECUTION PLAN to see if you're using index.  (If you have an index on the date-column of course).

Answer (score 0):

have you try this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS score FROM requests WHERE date_em BETWEEN '2019-04-01 00:00' AND '2019-04-30 23:59'
```

add 00:00 and 23:59 to make it look like a DateTime.